# Rails Spree demands account creation after bootstrapping without sample data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm using the Spree Rails gem for my ecommerce site. During development I've been using the sample data. After re-bootstrapping the database using "rake db:bootstrap" and this time NOT loading sample data, any time I go to any page on my site, it redirects me to /users/new.

I have removed all my custom route rules.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that (I'm pretty sure) the problem was due to there being no records in the 'users' table, as Spree apparently requires at least one user of role admin.